# The purpose of cgi.parse_qs

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Suppose this is the url

```
 domaint.tld/script?i=abc
```

this is the script:

```
from cgi import parse_qs

def application(environ, start_response):

    a = parse_qs(environ['QUERY_STRING'])
    a = a.get('i', [''])[0]

    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    yield a
```

the output is:

```
 abc
```

but URL can actually look even shorter.. like this.

```
  domaint.tld/script?abc
```

and the wsgi script can even be faster i suppose given that it does not have to import anything..

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    a = environ['QUERY_STRING']
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    yield a
```

the output is same as above..

```
 abc
```

is there a reason why someone should use URLS with `=` signs and a variable name.. ?
when it can be done this way that looks even more robust ?

Comment: Your comment "and the wsgi script can even be faster" is indicating that you are trying to prematurely optimise things. Speed should not be your first concern.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this function is indeed to parse a more complex query string such as

```
i=3&j=5&...
```

which is used for passing several values.

If you only have one value, it is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

The `name=value` form is a *standard*, produced by any browser submitting a form.

You are free to use your own format here, sure, but when you are using a *HTML form tag*, your browser will produce the query-string using the HTML standard to produce a query string with `&` separators between fields and each field represented as `name=value` pairs.

So, if you have full control over how the URL is being produced and you only need to pass on one value, just use the `?value` form. If you are dealing with forms or tools that are designed to produce the same format, stick with `parse_qs`.